# Google Cloud Platform not letting me delete project

Tags: google-cloud-platform

3 new projects suddenly appeared in my Google Cloud.  I don't know where they came from, and I can't delete them.

Following the delete instructions: https://cloud.google.com/go/getting-started#delete-the-project

When I select each of the projects to delete, the delete button disables, and shows the float over message:

```
You need permissions for this action.
Required permission(s): resourcemanager.projects.delete
```

All my other projects are fine, and I can delete them.

The three new projects that suddenly appeared are:

```
My Project 64342    brave-watch-314519
My Project 82497    beaming-light-336511
You can see this project    you-can-see-this-project
```

Screenshot:

[image]

How do I give myself permission to delete them?

**Note 1:** I am the only owner/user of this Google Cloud account.

**Note 2:** I also tried going to IAM -> Roles, but got the error:

[image]

Many thanks.

Comment: You may have messed up IAM by yourself (since there is nobody else to blame) or this may be a technical issue on the GCP side. When it cannot even perform `iam.roles.list`, there's not much one can do; I'd suggest opening a support ticket, in case this should persist.

Comment: Same happens to me, I have Elimuhub project, which I cannot delete and I have no connection with it. Some bug on Google side

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems to be a known issue with GCP. Leaving **“Google Groups”** related to GCP is a fix to this issue. You can track this **[Public Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/191214686)** for more information.

You might have been added into a project through a group, so it appears in the project list. However, you have not been granted permission to modify the IAM of that project, so you can't remove the group from the permission list.

As a workaround, you can leave **"Google Groups"** related to GCP and reload the GCP console webpage so that all your unknown/inaccessible projects will disappear from the projects list. You can find what groups you're a member of, using this **[Google Groups link](https://groups.google.com/my-groups)**.

**NOTE :** You can leave the groups in order to lose the access, but there could be a situation where your email is added to a single role/permission and you would not be able to remove yourself from the IAM list.